# jplayer plying local media file

Tags: mp3, playback, jplayer

I am using jplayer to play a mp3 file, which is is on my local machine itself. But player is unable to play.
       Here is my code.

```
       $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
                    ready: function () {
                      $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {

                        //m4a: location1
                        oga: location2,
                        mp3: "http://172.17.4.45/test.mp3"
                      });
                    },
                    swfPath: "<?php echo $base;?>/jplayer/",
                    supplied: "m4a, oga, mp3"
                  });
```

How can I accomplish this. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

Set up the player

```
  jQuery("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
       swfPath: "http://www.jplayer.org/latest/js/Jplayer.swf",
  supplied: "mp3",
  wmode: "window",
  preload:"auto",
  autoPlay: true,
  errorAlerts:false,
  warningAlerts:false
});
```

Load the track

```
  jQuery("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer(
  "setMedia", {
    mp3: "http://xxxx.rackcdn.com/"+track_id+".MP3"
  });
```

Play it!

```
  jQuery("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("play");
```

This should work. If not there must be someting with the filepaths.